# Disable all formfields except 1 field after change a select box

Tags: jquery

if a user change the option of a selectbox i want to disable all the fields inside the form without the triggering select-box and one specific input-field with id=xyz.

How i can do it in the fast and easiest way.

"#newsite_IS_HELPER" is the id of the selectbox

```
$('#newsite_IS_HELPER').change(function(){
    alert('What i have to do?');
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by *without the triggering select-box.*

Comment: the selectbox wich was changed should not disabled (and one specia input field too) - ive edit the code above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by selecting all input elements under your form, and excluding what you don't want to select i.e. `this` element (one which is triggering the disabling action i.e. `select` in your case) and the input element with `#xyz`.

```
$('#your_form_id :input:not(#xyz):not(#newsite_IS_HELPER)').prop("disabled", true);
```

```js
$('#newsite_IS_HELPER').change(function(){
    var this_val = $(this).val();
    var disable_all = false;
    if(this_val != "1"){
        disable_all = true;
    }
    $('#your_form_id :input:not(#xyz):not(#newsite_IS_HELPER)').prop("disabled", disable_all );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="your_form_id">
  <input id="xyz">
  <input><input><input><input><input>
  <select id="newsite_IS_HELPER">
  <option value="1">enable all</option><option value="2">disable all</option><option value="3">disable all again</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Comment: how i can do "not" for two elements?

Comment: @newbieRB yes you can do a `:not` for 2 elements as i did. check the fiddle

Comment: if i change back the select field, the input fields should be activate again, what i have to change in your code for that?

Comment: @newbieRB you will need to check the value of `select`. check the snippet in my answer, i've updated it with condition check to re-enable the `input` elements

Answer (score 0):

How I do,

```
$ ('#newsite_IS_HELPER').change(function(){ 
   $("input").attr("disabled", "disabled");       
   $(this).attr("disabled",false);
   $("#xyz").attr("disabled",false);
 });
```

Or-else, you can use prop in place of attr, like bellow my code,

```
$("input").prop('disabled', true);
```